# Example figure placement

Tags: floats, best-practices, examples

I am using the following code in an example file.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{box}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:one}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: example rendering]

This means that there has to be an image named 'box' in the same directory (e.g. box.pdf). Is there a way to avoid that? I was thinking about an example image that ships with TeX-Live anyway or some tikZ solution? Which would be the most portable way of defining such an example without the necessity of a second file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of possibilities

- use the `demo` option with the `graphicx` package: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`
- use the [`mwe`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mwe) package, which gives you access to a few images- a MWE (!) is shown below

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:one}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: <s>I like the `[demo]` solution, because it is so easy to switch on and off. However, some portability is lost, you cannot use the `mhchem` package in the example any more.</s> It seams that I just have to load the demoed `graphicx`-package first.

Comment: @Andy I experimented and loaded the `mhchem` just fine- could you give more details?

Comment: You have to load the `mhchem` package after the `[demo]{graphicx}` package, at least in the actual non-MWE example I am trying. I figured that out only after commenting and tried to strikeout the earlier part of my comment. Therefore, a totally unrelated question: Is there a way to strikeout comments. I am sure I have seen it in questions and answers.